# Arduino RXTX Loop

Tags: serial-port, arduino, xbee

I am working with 2 arduinos with an xbee attached to each one. I want 1 arduino to be the master and the second be the slave. I am trying to send over serial a command like

```
Serial.write("Get Arduino1 Data");
```

Then I want the other arduino to recieve this string and have something similar to

```
if(inString == "Get Arduino1 Data") {
 Serial.write("Your data here");
 Serial.write(digitalRead(4));
}
```

The problem is 
1) I cannot get the 2nd arduino to go into the if statement and the arduinos sit and rx then tx, rx then tx, etc and a pile of repeated "Get Arduino1 Data" strings overflow the monitor.

Any help?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xbee.  But, taking a shot -- How does your receiver read the bytes?   To do it this way, you'd need to read each byte (ignore when there is not a byte), append it to a String, and test after each byte if the string matched.  But there could also an extra byte introduced somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the PhysicalPixel example into the Communucation examples of the Arduino IDE

```
void loop() {
// see if there's incoming serial data:
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
// read the oldest byte in the serial buffer:
incomingByte = Serial.read();
// if it's a capital H (ASCII 72), turn on the LED:
   if (incomingByte == 'H') {
     digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
   } 
// if it's an L (ASCII 76) turn off the LED:
   if (incomingByte == 'L') {
     digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
   }
}
}
```

remember that you have to use a SoftwareSerial and the XBee module must use AT mode